# BlueImp File upload extra parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file-upload, blueimp

I am trying to pass an extra parameter to the blueimp file upload. And I tried using the file upload submit event:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
// The example input, doesn't have to be part of the upload form:
var input = $('#input');
data.formData = {example: input.val()};
if (!data.formData.example) {
  data.context.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  input.focus();
  return false;
}
});
```

However I have no idea where that extra parameter is being passed to and how to access that extra paremeter?

What I am trying to achieve is to assign a unique id to each row when the files are uploaded in the UI version. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your upload-template javascript add the field

```js
<td>
Descripción
 <input type="text" name="descripcion[]" id="descripcion" placeholder="Descripción">     
</td>
```

In your jQueryFileUpload

```js
}).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
  var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
  if (inputs.filter(function () {
    return !this.value && $(this).prop('required');
  }).first().focus().length) {
   data.context.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  return false;
  }
  data.formData = data.context.find(':input').serializeArray();
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But how do I retrieve the description? Can I output it in the download template?

Answer (score 0):

First, the template-download add this code

```js
<td>
  {%=file.descripcion%}
</td>
```

And then modifies your custom index.php "set_additional_file_properties ($ file)" function

```html
protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
        parent::set_additional_file_properties($file);
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
            $sql = "SELECT Id, Nombre, Descripcion FROM tabla WHERE Nombre='".$file->name."'";
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result(
                $id,
                $nombre,
                $descripcion
            );
            while ($query->fetch()) {
                $file->id = $id;
                $file->nombre = $nombre;
                $file->descripcion = utf8_encode($descripcion);
            }
        }
  
    }
```